# ng-show angular tab with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-show, angularjs-controlleras

I have been working on this for a while now and cannot figure out why it will not work. [This](http://plnkr.co/edit/RAeIwFbn2Zoe9WfLdMX8?p=preview) is the effect I am trying to create- http://plnkr.co/edit/RAeIwFbn2Zoe9WfLdMX8?p=preview. I wish to have create a tab bar that when clicked on will show different information.

This is the code I have so far, but it will not work for some reason:

**HTML**

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
 <li ng-repeat="tablet in Packages.panelTabs">
    <a href ng-click="tab = tablet.tabNum"> 
      {{tablet.name}}
    </a>
 </li>
    <p ng-show="tab === 1"> Tab1 content </p>           
    <p ng-show="tab === 2"> Tab2 content</p> 
 </ul>
```

**JS**

My angular code looks like this.

```
this.panelTabs = [

            {
                name: "package-price",
                tabNum: 1
            },
            {
                name: "package-description",
                tabNum: 2
            }
        ];
```

I have read various answers and tried many things, but feel it must be something stupid I am missing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, Paul

Comment: try `Packages.tab = tab.tabNum`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While setting `tab` model do declare it in parent scope by using `$parent` keyword. The reason on each iteration `ng-repeat` directive does create a new prototypically inherited scope.

**Markup**

```
<li ng-repeat="tablet in Packages.panelTabs">
   <a href ng-click="$parent.tab = tablet.tabNum"> 
      {{tablet.name}}
   </a>
</li>
```

@azium suggested to use `controllerAs` because you are already using it by using `Packages` as alias of your controller. Now put tab variable inside your controller variable like `Packages.tab`

**Markup**

```
<li ng-repeat="tablet in Packages.panelTabs">
   <a href ng-click="Packages.tab = tablet.tabNum"> 
      {{tablet.name}}
   </a>
</li>
<p ng-show="Packages.tab === 1"> Tab1 content </p>           
<p ng-show="Packages.tab === 2"> Tab2 content</p>
```

Comment: Looks like he might be using `controller as` so `Packages` instead of `$parent` would be better.

Comment: @azium better than that would be `dot rule` while declaring model

Comment: @azium good shout, have changed it to Packages.tab and it works, and now makes far more sense. Thank you both

Comment: @PankajParkar doesn't `controller as` enforce the dot rule? In your second example you're still not referring to the scope which is the whole point of `controller as`